# PHP - How does constructor parse data when inheriting?

Tags: php, oop

I have 2 classes, one extends the other:

```
class Human {
    const PERKS = 'none';
    public function __construct() {
        echo self::PERKS;
    }
}

class King extends Human {
    const PERKS = 'crown';
}
```

Ignore the silly example. However, no matter whom I initialize I get printed 'none'.

1. How exactly does the constructor work?
2. How can I get around this?

Thank you.

Comment: Read there - http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`self` always refers to exact class in which it's used. From [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php):

> Static references to the current class like self:: or **CLASS** are resolved using the class in which the function belongs, as in where it was defined.

To work around this, you can use the `static` class resolution operator, which is resolved at runtime instead, e.g.

```
class Human {
    const PERKS = 'none';
    public function __construct() {
        echo static::PERKS;
    }
}

class King extends Human {
    const PERKS = 'crown';
}

new King;
// crown

new Human;
// none
```

See https://eval.in/959784